# Assimp Import Non Deform Bones

Tags: opengl, assimp

I want to import an fbx file, that has non deform bones. However at default Assimp doesn't seem to import bones that have at least one vertex assigned to them. And I can't find any options in Assimp's documentation to change this.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the latest master version. There is a new version upcoming which has a great support for the FBX-support. This was not supported in the latest version ( really buggy ). If the features are not supported correctly please feel free to add a new issue.

Thanks, Kim!